# Good idea to ignore errors?

Tags: php, error-reporting

I found out that on my system "error_reporting" was turned off. So I turned it on (E_ALL) and now I have quite a lot errors.

if you're interested in my mistakes:

```
Notice: Undefined index: page in …path/file.php on line 22
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in …path/file.php on line 49
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in …path/file.php on line 57
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in …path/file.php on line 58
Notice: Undefined variable: out in …path/file.php on line 85
Notice: Undefined variable: out in …path/file.php on line 109
Notice: Use of undefined constant M_DESCRIPTION - assumed 'M_DESCRIPTION' in …path/file.php on line 181
Notice: Use of undefined constant GA_TRACKER - assumed 'GA_TRACKER' in …path/file.php on line 291
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in …path/file.php on line 12
Notice: Undefined variable: attributes in …path/file.php on line 86
Notice: Undefined variable: li in …path/file.php on line 129
Notice: Undefined index: breakafterlabel in …path/file.php on line 175
Notice: Undefined index: afterlabel in …path/file.php on line 167
Notice: Undefined index: attributes in …path/file.php on line 188
Notice: Undefined index: value in …path/file.php on line 191
Notice: Undefined index: for in …path/file.php on line 163
Notice: Undefined index: attributes in …path/file.php on line 249
Notice: Undefined index: value in …path/file.php on line 299
Notice: Undefined variable: out in …path/file.php on line 109
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in …path/file.php on line 418
Notice: Undefined index: maxlength in …path/file.php on line 368
Notice: Undefined index: accept in …path/file.php on line 372
Notice: Undefined variable: out in …path/file.php on line 93
Notice: Undefined index: accept in …path/file.php on line 378
Notice: Undefined index: title in …path/file.php on line 379
Notice: Undefined index: accept in …path/file.php on line 402
Notice: Undefined index: fp in …path/file.php on line 624
Notice: Undefined variable: alert_msg in …path/file.php on line 246
Notice: Undefined variable: returner in …path/file.php on line 87
Notice: Undefined index: body in …path/file.php on line 309
Notice: Undefined variable: out in …path/file.php on line 81
Notice: Undefined variable: defaults in …path/file.php on line 121
```

First I thought "Oh you better turn it off again", but I'm not sure about the consequences!

So the very simple question is: Does it matter if I ignore all the errors or not?

Comment: You should fix them

Comment: Can you please explain why? Or do you have a link? Because I'm interested why I should fix them. What are the consequences?

Comment: @JohnDoeSmith ["Anything that can go wrong, will go wrong."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy's_law)

Comment: These are just Notices. Notices appear, when ever you do something that "works", but is not how it should be. i.e. if you are doing `$myAarray[] = 1` without doing `$myArray = array()` prior, you'll get a Notice about an undefined variable $myArray, for the first access. It's not critical, it just is *uncomplete/dirty code*. Consequences of not resolving it? You produce a lot of log-entrys and overview while searching *real* errors will suffer.

Comment: using `isset` could fix most of those errors.

Comment: @JohnDoeSmith Are you _really_ asking, why you should fix bugs?!? O_o

Comment: @dognose Not only annoying and causing a huge log file: Notices are good hints, were you _maybe_ have a bug. They are not critical from the interpreter point-of-view, but maybe from the applications ;)

Comment: @dognose doing `$myArray[] = 1` does not raise an `E_NOTICE`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a development environment it's best to work with `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, so you can see notices as well. This encourages you to have a higher coding standard.

When running a live site, you MUST have `display_errors off`, but log your errors (just like you're doing).

This way, you will only see errors that have meaning, and not only "Notice: Undefined ...". If the website is already done, you should spend a bit of time refactoring your code, the long-term benefits will be worth it.

Comment: In production environment I prefer `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, `display_errors = Off`, `log_errors = On` and `error_log = /some/file/errors.log`

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to hide temporarily some message errors, use an @ :

```
echo @$undefined;
@session_start;
```

**This will not solve your error**, but make your error listing clearer while you are **fixing it**.

Answer (score 1):

**The answer is: no!**
Ignoring errors might cause unexpected behaviors. In addition it may slow down the execution of your program / script. So you better not ignoring but fix them.

Do be more detailed: Where the `Undefined offset` errors are unproblematic in most cases, a `Use of undefined constant` constant or a failed `session_start` may be dangerous.

Comment: If you log them you may run into issues like that: [2bits.com](http://2bits.com/drupal/avoid-excessive-disk-writes-avoiding-php-errors-your-code.html)

Where they say "Moral of the story: don't have php-errors and notices in the first place."

Answer (score -1):

You should pay attention to the errors and warnings.
They are you saying that you have done something wrong in .

The errors are very useful in a a development environment.
But when you release the code, it's best to disable them.